# How to prevent concurrent login for a web application using express-session

Tags: express, authentication, express-session, login-control

I am creating a web application which will be used by App's Administrators and for security reasons we don't want to allow multiple active logins from a single user at any point of time.

I am storing session data in the web browser's `cookie` and want backend to have active user's information who are currently logged in to the application so that on successful login request I can find out if this particular user already has an active session. If that is possible then I can block the login for that user.

One way to do that is storing `IsLoggedIn` in the `Database` with `LastLoginTime` and on each login, I can use this two flags to identify if an active session exists.

Open to other better solutions if any

Answer (score 1):

I think a more robust solution than checking last login times would be to generate and store an `id` for each new login and then include a middleware to make sure the session's `id` for each user matches what you expect. That way every time the user logs in on another device the previous one will be invalidated and only one session will be valid at a time. You may even just be able to use `express-session`'s `req.session.id`.

Comment: That way every time the user logs in on another device the previous one will be invalidated and only one session will be valid at a time. -> I don't want to invalidate the previous login, instead new login attempts should be invalidated.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your question a bit. I still think you will need to use a unique identifier instead of a simple boolean though if you "don't want to allow multiple active logins from a single user at any point of time." Because if you don't the best you can do is just don't allow users to log in multiple times over a short period of time.